# lista de archivos cmd

Tags: cmd

Buenas,

tengo un problema para hacer listados de los archivos que hay en las carpetas.

Tengo una carpeta que contiene varias carpetas dentro, y dentro de cada subcarpeta hay varios archivos *.txt. Lo que quiero es que dentro de cada subcarpeta haya un txt con la información de la ruta:

```
C:\TimeSeries\New folder\Archivo_1.txt
C:\TimeSeries\New folder\Archivo_2.txt
```

En la carpeta *New folder* aparecerá un txt con la información de arriba. En la carpeta *New folder 2* aparecerá:

```
C:\TimeSeries\New folder 2\Archivo_1.txt
C:\TimeSeries\New folder 2\Archivo_2.txt
```

Esto lo puedo hacer metiéndome en la subcarpeta (por ejemplo, en *New folder*) y escribiendo en la cmd:

```
dir/s/b *.txt > list_of_files.txt
```

Pero al tener muchas subcarpetas lo que quiero es situarme en la carpeta que contiene todas las subcarpetas y con un comando, un bucle o algo así que me recorra todas las subcarpetas y me guarde un archivo txt en cada subcarpeta con la lista de archivos correspondientes.

No estoy segura de si se puede hacer.

Gracias!

#### Actualización:

Para conseguir el listado de todas las subcarpetas con la ruta completa se necesita abrir la consola en la carpeta que contiene las subcarpetas y poner lo siguiente:

```
for /f "delims=" %D in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir /s/b "%~fD\*.txt" > "%~fD\list_of_files.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que es posible hacerlo, usando un fichero batch. Crea un fichero con extension `.bat` (por ejemplo, lista.bat). Editalo y pon lo siguiente:

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir "%%~fD\*.*" > "%%~fD\list_of_files.txt"
```

luego ejecuta `lista.bat` y verás que te ha creado un archivo `list_of_files`en cada subcarpeta con el `dir` de cada una.

Explicación del comando:

- `for /f` recorre y procesa cada uno de los archivos especificados en la parte de `in`, en este caso `dir /a:d /b`
- `"delims="` se usa para que el for no trate de buscar "tokens", sino que devuelva el texto completo.
- `dir /a:d /b`:Obtiene un listado solo de los directorios, sin ningún tipo de encabezado
- Para cada directorio obtenido, se hace un `dir directorio\*.* > directorio\list_of_files.txt`, generando el listado de archivos del subdirectorio en un archivo dentro del mismo subdirectorio.
- `%%~f` significa expandir la variable siguiente a su path completo

Alternativamente, si no quieres crear un `bat`, puede directamente en línea de comandos ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
for /f "delims=" %D in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir "%~fD\*.*" > "%~fD\list_of_files.txt"
```

**Editado**

En los comentarios dices que necesitas almacenar la ruta completa de cada archivo. Para ello,necesitas hacer un segundo `for` dentro de cada carpeta. En un fichero bat estos sería:

```
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /a:d /b') do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%%~fX" /b ') do echo "%%~fa" >> "%%~fX\list_of_files.txt"
```

y si lo vas a ejecutar en línea de comandos:

```
for /f "delims=" %X in ('dir /a:d /b') do for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir "%~fX" /b ') do echo "%~fa" >> "%~fX\list_of_files.txt"
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70044/discussion-between-ahinoa-and-pikoh).